# Share on Facebook from Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, vb6, facebook-javascript-sdk

My application in VB 6.0 is generating some graphs. Is there any way to share these graphs on Facebook as images ?

Right now we are sharing graphs with print screen, and then login to Facebook and paste it.

Comment: Just quick comment: VBA is not the same as VB6 (although closely related). So I have removed VBA reference.

Answer (score 0):

How you handle this will depend on how you're generating the graphs.  If you're using intrinsic controls and drawing on something like an Image/PictureBox control, you'll just need to write the image to disk in your preferred format with GDI+ (here's a good JPG [example](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/savejpggdip.shtml) to get you started)

If you're using 3rd party controls for the Graph, you'll need to see what's available to you from their API, or perhaps update the question to include exactly what controls you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I can generate desired image on disc but not getting, how can I share this on Facebook.

Comment: For the specifics of how to post to Facebook you'll need to read up on http://developer.facebook.com, specifically the [Share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) button.

Comment: Also found [this](http://i-won-help-u.blogspot.com/p/a-simple-code-very-easy-for-beginners.html) with a sample using the share button in vb6.